# background linear gradient of the page on Android 4.0.4 changes on scroll and touch

Tags: jquery, css, html, jquery-mobile

I am testing the webpage on the Andriod device with the version 4.0.4. The background of the website is set to the linear gradient.

```
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#afe3f3 10% /*{a-body-background-start}*/), to(#FFFFFF 35% /*{a-body-background-end}*/)); /* Saf4+, Chrome */
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient( #a1ddf1 10% /*{a-body-background-start}*/, #FFFFFF 35% /*{a-body-background-end}*/); /* Chrome 10+, Saf5.1+ */
background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient( #a1ddf1 10% /*{a-body-background-start}*/, #FFFFFF 35% /*{a-body-background-end}*/); /* FF3.6 */
background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient( #a1ddf1 10% /*{a-body-background-start}*/, #FFFFFF 35% /*{a-body-background-end}*/); /* IE10 */
background-image:      -o-linear-gradient( #a1ddf1 10% /*{a-body-background-start}*/, #FFFFFF 35% /*{a-body-background-end}*/); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background-image:         linear-gradient( #a1ddf1 10% /*{a-body-background-start}*/, #FFFFFF 35%/*{a-body-background-end}*/);
background-attachment: fixed;
```

When I try to enter data in the fields and the keyboard is displayed, The gradient percentage keeps changing which results in changing colors randomly.

Does anyone know the fix for this problem?

I tried to add the style using jQuery on window resize but it does not work.

```
var initialScreenSize = window.innerHeight;
window.addEventListener("resize", function () {
    if (window.innerHeight < initialScreenSize) {
        $("[data-role=footer]").hide();
    }
    else {
        $("[data-role=footer]").show();
    }

    var isAndroid = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('android') > -1;
     if (isAndroid) {
           $("[data-role=page]").css('background-image', '-webkit-linear-gradient( #afe3f3 10% , #FFFFFF 35%');

    }
});
```

Comment: Does element has a dynamic height?

Comment: It is the static height. the min-height is set to the content of the div.                                                         div[data-role="content"] {
    background-attachment: fixed;
    min-height: 200px;
    padding-left: 10%;
    padding-right: 10%;
}